# Hexadecimal conversion in FAT32 BIOS parameter block

Tags: hex, endianness, fat32

I am a bit confused, what is the difference between `0x0002` and `0x02`. I am trying to understand the [FAT boot sector](http://www.ntfs.com/fat-partition-sector.htm), and I am stuck as I don't understand why these two values are interpreted differently. When I paste both values in a hex to decimal converter it returns 2 in both cases, rightly so.

Why are these values interpreted differently by the operating system, and what is the effect of leading zeros on hexadecimal numbers.

[image: BIOS Parameter Block and Extended BIOS Parameter Block Fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that the values in the FAT are stored in little endian, thus `0x0002` is reverted to `0x0200` which is `512` in base 10. `02` is just 2 in base 10.

Comment: Actually 0x0200 is 512 in base 16 (every base is 10 in it's own base notwithstanding). The hexadecimal representation in the article is misleading and incorrect. All numbers (including hex) are represented in "big endian" format. To present the on disk "little endian" format a WORD value would be 0x00, 0x02.

Comment: Well, look in the size column: 0x0002 is 16bits and 0x02 is 8bits. Consider this, `0xFFFF` versus `0xFF`.